# Retrieve a file from an API action using FRAPI

Tags: php, rest, download, frapi

I am using frapi as my API framework, and am looking to make an Action to that will send a file to the client making the request. For example https://api.domain.com/list/today will return a .csv file to the client.  I have put some thought into this and came up with two possible solutions.

One is to send the URL of the resource via JSON and have the application handle downloading it on that end.

Another is to push a header with "application/zip" or something of the like to the browser.

I am generally looking for what would be the best way to go about this, and not limited to the aforementioned solutions.